# Visual Studio Code not opening project in MAC

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

So I came back to my work station on Monday monring and when I opened a project in VSC . It is not showing folders and files in the workspace.
On Command line also when I am trying to do any git operation getting this error

"unable to get current working directory: Operation not permitted"

Any idea what happened here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be it is happening because your system preferences have been automatically changed due to recent upgrade.

Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab

Select "Full Disk Access" from the left-side menu

Add Terminal, iTerm or Visual Studio Code any more for which you are getting errors to the app list.

Details: https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Comment: Thanks, yes its look like those settings needs to updated. Its working now after that.